Common Indoeuropean Phonotactics Rules
What kinds of phonotactics restrictions/rules are rather widespread in Indoeuropean languages nowadays? The kinds of sound-combination rules that if broken would immediately sound 'faraway'? Obviously many won't be universal, but which ones are at least represented in the current major languages descended from PIE?

Each language has its own set of phonotactic restrictions; being an Indo-European language doesn’t come with any special restrictions. Some restrictions will be more common than others, but those restrictions will also most likely be more common outside Indo-European (e.g., disallowing initial clusters like /lk/ or /kg/ is near-universal in Indo-European languages, but probably as near-universal globally).

@JanusBahsJacquet These clusters are allowed in Slavic languages after loss of weak yers, e.g. Czech lkát. (Although (1) /g/ evolved to /ɦ/ in several languages, and (2) consonants have voicedness assimilation in most languages (so e.g. /kg/ → [gg], or /kɦ/ → [ɡɦ]). There may be only few such words, but if we search for some different initial clusters like /kt/ or /pt/, then they can be found in basic vocabulary, e.g. kto / кто, ptak / pták / птах.)

@Arfrever Is Czech lkát not two syllables (i.e., with syllabic /l/)? Voicedness assimilation was implicitly disallowed in my example (should perhaps have used [lk] and [kg] instead) – but even allowing it, can you give some examples of words that start with tautosyllabic /kg/? I can’t find any on Wiktionary that start with orthographic ⟨kg⟩ (or ⟨кг⟩) except a bunch of words in Old Ruthenian, where ⟨кг⟩ seems to be used for /g/ like ⟨ґ⟩ in various modern languages.

@JanusBahsJacquet Syllabic [l̩] and [r̩] survived only in Czech and Slovak, but they developed into [l] or [r] preceded or followed by various vowels in other Slavic languages (e.g. Czech vlk - Polish wilk, Russian волк; Czech krk - Polish kark). Czech lkát and lhát (where [lɦ] ← [lg]) are 1-syllable words, and their Polish equivalents are łkać and łgać (in Polish: [l] → [ɫ] → [u̯], but pronunciation with [ɫ] exists dialectally or archaically).

@JanusBahsJacquet I am not claiming that tautosyllabic /kg/ or [kk] or [gg] actually exists, but that phonotactic rules of Slavic languages allow slightly long sequence (with limit not below 4 consonants) of different or identical tautosyllabic consonants (with the same voicedness amongst obstruents), including maybe 2 consecutive plosives or affricates. In Czech there are basic words such as kde [ˈɡdɛ], kdo [ˈɡdo], kdy [ˈɡdɪ], which show voicedness assimilation.

@JanusBahsJacquet  In Czech, I found surname Khýn [ˈɡɦiːn]. If it existed in early medieval times, before /g/ → /ɦ/ change in Old Czech, then it would start with /kg/ at that time. Some examples of initial /t͡ʂt͡ʂ/ and /d͡ʐd͡ʐ/ in Polish: czczy, czczący, dżdżysty, dżdżyć, dżdżownica.

@JanusBahsJacquet Phrasing in my earlier comment was wrong. "different or identical tautosyllabic consonants" should have been something like "tautosyllabic consonants (including 2 identical consecutive consonants)". I will also mention that at least [ss], [zz], [vv] at initial position are also attested. Examples: ssać, ssak, ssawka, zza, wwozić.

@Arfrever Okay, so Czech/Slovak and perhaps dialectal Polish allow initial /lk/ – that’s still a very small part of the ~450 Indo-European languages currently spoken. As for Khýn, I can’t find any authoritative sources for its etymology, but a comment on Přijmení.cz claims it’s from German Kien ‘pine’ (a similarly random-looking page says the similar name Khun is from [older] German Kuonrad); if that’s true, the ⟨kh⟩ may simply be to represent the aspirated German /kʰ/, and /gɦiːn/ then just a spelling pronunciation.

@Arfrever Also, the existence of a rarely allowed feature somewhere doesn’t negate its rarity. Initial clusters like [stsʼqʰtsʰtʰx] are attested, but they are extremely underrepresented in the phonotactics of the world’s languages, Indo-European or otherwise.

@JanusBahsJacquet In Russian, I cannot find initial лк, but лг is attested, e.g. лгать (which is equivalent of Czech lhát / Polish łgać mentioned earlier). Maybe Khýn is from German; I do not know its etymology. More generally, if there was a (not late) Proto-Slavic word starting with *[kig-] or *[kug-], then by regular sound changes it may have developed into /kg-/ (similarly to how *[kude] developed to Czech kde, Russian где, Polish gdzie). It seems that there simply happened to be no such words in Proto-Slavic.

I suspect there are very few phonotactic restrictions that are disproportionately common in Indo-European languages, because almost all the phonotactic restrictions present in PIE have been lost in almost all branches.
PIE had several notable phonotactic restrictions:

No initial vowels. This was lost (at least on the phonemic level) with the loss of initial pre-vocalic laryngeals. It's also pretty common cross-linguistically.
No initial *r-. This was lost with the loss of initial pre-consonantal laryngeals (except in Greek and Armenian, where it was lost for other reasons). This or similar traits appears quite common in Northern Eurasia.
At most one resonant (*r, *l, *m, *n, *y, & *w) in coda (two resonants at the end of a root prohibited, otherwise avoided by vocalising the second resonant). Weaker forms may persist, but are also pretty common cross-linguistically. This full form has mostly been lost to syncope, apocope, or analogy.
Acceptance of initial *wl-, *wr- (but other initial clusters of two non-syllabic resonants generally avoided). This has generally been lost with either the *w being lost, or fortiting to /v/ which then no longer violates the sonority hierarchy. Secondary instances may also have been created in some instances.
No *y after a heavy sequence (i.e. V̆CC or V̄C) in the same word. This may not have been present in PIE, but this restricted version of Sievers' Law does seem to have applied in Germanic, Sanskrit, and Greek, so likely did. This has been lost due to various other sound changes creating secondary instances of *y from other sources (that outside Germanic do not seem to have been affected), and from changes to the preceding sequences making previously heavy sequences light (or previously light sequences heavy), rendering the alternation conditions opaque (except in Germanic where they continued to apply according to the synchronic conditions until shortly before the attestation of Gothic (where the alternations are still largely transparent). Additionally, in many languages post-consonantal *y & *iy (the other alternant) merged, or else one or both coalesced with the preceding consonant causing palatalisation and again removing the alternation.
No geminates. This was lost in most branches pretty early, but has now arisen again independently in many of them. This is pretty common cross-linguistically.
Limited violation of sonority hierarchy. This is still pretty well maintained in most branches (Slavic being a notable exception), but is also extremely common cross-linguistically so not of any real diagnostic utility.
A root cannot have two plain voiced stops, or a voiceless stop & a voiced aspirated stop. In many branches this has been lost by mergers of the various series (Celtic, Balto-Slavic, Albanian, & Iranic do this in all positions, whilst Germanic & Italic do it conditionally), with loans (either from substrates or other branches) destroying the restriction in the other branches.

So none of those have been inherited in any way that could be easily distinguished from cross-linguistic trends.
The one trait I've occasionally seen given, that might work, is actually not a PIE phonotactic rule at all, because it involves a segment that was certainly not phonemic in PIE:

[ŋ] only before velars and (due to the restrictions on sonority hierarchy, not word-initially). PIE itself had no /ŋ/, but it developed in most branches as an allophone of /n/ (possibly also /m/) before velars. This restriction isn't exactly unusual cross-linguistically, and has been lost in many IE languages (e.g. English where earlier /ŋg/ > /ŋ/, granting it full phonemic status; or Albanian where procope led to previously word-internal /ŋg/ becoming word-initial), but is probably slightly more prevalent amongst IE languages than the global average where most languages with a phonemic /ŋ/ have no issue with it appearing word-initially.


The last point in the list doesn’t look right to me. LIV² has six roots beginning in *men- (one uncertain) and two in *nem-; five roots beginning in *i̯eu̯- (two uncertain) and 11 in *u̯ei̯- (three uncertain), which seems rather a lot if such roots were phonotactically avoided – and that’s not counting roots like *tu̯ei̯s- where the offending combination is not initial. If we assume laryngeals were fricatives, the frequency of roots like *h₂eh₁s-, *h₂emh₃- or even *h₁es-, the most basic of all roots, would also speak against a restriction on fricatives.

that's an excellent point! I was looking over a list of restrictions and forgot to actually check how valid they seemed to be. I'll remove that one
